# How to direct an EDI file down a certain path in Control flow task

Tags: ssis, control-flow, edi

So I have an SSIS package that I am working on right now that requires something that I have yet to do. The package currently just has a For Each Loop container that stores the value of the file name it finds in the User::WatchFolder to a variable and then moves that file to another folder for a process to pick up. What I have been tasked with is augmenting this so that the process remains unchanged for .837 file that does not contain a certain set of character but redirecting the files that come through with the word 'RELAY' in them. From there I also need to open up this EDI file and replace the string '5010' with '5010R', save it and move to a separate folder.

I have moved data in a Data flow task based on certain criteria using a Conditional Split, but this is not data from a table or database, so I'm not sure if this can be accomplished in a Control Flow task. Also, I'm assuming that the string can be replaced via a Script Task, but I'm not sure (again) if this is something that would live in the Control flow or in some sort of Data Flow task.

This is what the package looks like thus far. 
[SSIS Package so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbcaj.png)

EDIT: So far I have created a script task using C# to find and replace the values using ReadFile(FilePath) into a variable called FileContent and then doing a FileContent.Replace("someText","someOtherText")
and then writing the contents back to the file using StreamReader and StreamWriter. That part seems to work fine, but I'm not sure now how to move the file depending on whether it contains a certain value in the FileName.

```
public void Main()
    {
        String ErrInfo = "";
        String FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString();
        try
        {
            String FileContent; //Variable to store File Contents
            FileContent = ReadFile(FilePath, ErrInfo);
            if (ErrInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                Dts.Log("Error while reading File " + FilePath, 0, null);
                Dts.Log(ErrInfo, 0, null);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                return;
            }


            //FileContent Before Replace;
            MessageBox.Show(FileContent);

            //Find and Replace --> Modify WHERE clause
            FileContent = FileContent.Replace(
               "Relay5010 ",
               "Relay5010R" 
            );

            //FileContent After Replace;
            MessageBox.Show(FileContent);
            Dts.Variables["User::FileContent"].Value = FileContent;

            //Write the contents back to File
            WriteToFile(FilePath, FileContent, ErrInfo);
            if (ErrInfo.Length > 0)
            {
                Dts.Log("Error while writing File " + FilePath, 0, null);
                Dts.Log(ErrInfo, 0, null);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Dts.Log(e.Message, 0, null);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }

    public String ReadFile(String FilePath, String ErrInfo)
    {
        String strContents;
        StreamReader sReader;
        try
        {
            sReader = File.OpenText(FilePath);
            strContents = sReader.ReadToEnd();
            sReader.Close();
            return strContents;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ErrInfo);
            ErrInfo = e.Message;
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void WriteToFile(String FilePath, String strContents, String ErrInfo)
    {
        StreamWriter sWriter;
        try
        {
            sWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePath);
            sWriter.Write(strContents);
            sWriter.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ErrInfo);
            ErrInfo = e.Message;
        }
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

  }
}
```

Truth is, I'd love to leave the existing files alone and let them run down their normal path and just divert the ones containing the "R" value and those can have the script task applied to them. Is there possibly a way other than another script task? I am just trying to see if SSIS lends me another tool so that this can be done in the most straight forward way possible

This is my first question posted as well so if there is something else I missed here, I won't be offended if it is pointed out!

Comment: You may need script task to read each files to search if file has specific content you need. Also with in script task you may edit the file and move it to a different foleder.

Comment: It would be better if you could share pieces of codes which you worked on so far.